# CheckboxInput always displays ON

Tags: django

I have a CheckboxInput which gets/sets its value to a db, but the CheckboxInput always displays as ON. The db updates correctly and if i am to remove the CheckboxInput and make it a normal checkbox, the output displays correctly.

```
done = forms.NullBooleanField(label='Have you finished', required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'checked data-toggle':'toggle', 'data-on':'Yes', 'data-off':'No'}))
```

My question is how do i get the checkbox to be set to YES on True and NO on False.

Thank you

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry, i edited my post